# custom validation messages in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, grails-2.0

I have a domain constraint which I am validating like

```
userName(blank:false, nullable:false, Size: 5..50,matches:'^[A-Za-z\\d]*$',validator:{chkUser,user->if(user.loginService.getUser(user.organizationId,user.userName)!=null){
                                                                                                                    return[propertyName="userName"]}
                                                                                              })
```

So what I am trying to do is call login service and see if username exists. IF the username exists I have to return message USerName already exists. I have modified my message.properties as:

```
BuildUserNameCommand.userName.matches= Username Should have alphanumeric characters only
BuildUserNameCommand.userName.invalid.userName=Username already exists
BuildUserNameCommand.userName.validator.error= Username already exists
```

`buildusernamecommand` is my class name. I have also tried `return['invalid.userName']` in the constraint. But still its not displaying the custom message.

Help me out please....

Comment: which version of Grails are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Are you seeing any of the other custom messages for the command object like the matches one ?
Are usernames uniquely global or just unique within the scope of the organisation. If globally unique validation is easy with 
    unique:true

If just unique within scope of the organisation you could try return the string "alreadyExists" from  your validator, then define the message in the form:

```
buildUserNameCommand.userName.alreadyExists = 'Username already exists'
```

If that is not working, another option would be to return false from the validator. That might then pull in the message

```
buildUserNameCommand.userName.validator.error= Username already exists
```

Note the lowercase **b** on the class name. Not sure if the class needs to start with a lowercase letter but in my code they do, and it would seem to be more in keeping with Grails patterns.

Answer (score 3):

If you only have `Users` as a domain objects, it's easier to use [unique](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Constraints/unique.html) constraint:

```
username unique: true
```

Then, in your case, the message code to define would be `buildUserNameCommand.userName.unique` - and the constraint does it all for you. It will also generate DB schema uniqueness constraint.